# sending code from Neovim to Jupyter qtconsole

Tags: jupyter, neovim, qtconsole, neovim-plugin

I just newly switched to using neovim. Before this I used to use jupyter lab. So far I have configured vim-slime with neovim and can yank code from script into a ipython shell. The python shell cannot display matplotlib graphs by itself. for this reason I installed jupyter qtconsole which is more advanced and has a lot functionality. The problem is I can't figure out how to send code from vim to a qtconsole.

I tried opening **qtconsole** inside a terminal in neovim but it opens a seperate window and I can't send code to it.
I also tried using the **jupyter-vim** plugin but it didn't work. It only executed the file but nothing shows up the qtconsole window.
The **vim-ipython** plugin is also outdated and I can't figure out how to use it.